# Profiling/coverage: counting case alternative evaluations

Tags: haskell, profiling, code-coverage, ghc

`hpc markup --fun-entry-count` shows the number of times a top-level function has been entered.

I'm wondering if there is a similar option for other syntactic entities, in particular case alternatives. Basically I'm trying to optimise a big case statement and am wondering which branches are the most common ones.

From the docs it looks like there isn't. So is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a compiler option to do this all at once for all case expressions.  You can [insert Cost Center annotations manually](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#inserting-cost-centres-by-hand); the profiling output will have the number of entries and the time spent for each cost center.  Or you can move each alternative into a named function, at least while you're working on optimizing. I've taken both approaches in the past.

Comment: That works, thanks! (Although it would be nice if hpc could do that...)